# I created app for local sqlite database but it not running. Please tell me the solution

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This is DatabaseHelper.java class, in this class I write query for SQLite Database. I think there is not any problem in query.

```
package com.example.ankurnamikaze.myapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.R.attr.name;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes_db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
public static final String COL_ID = "id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_PASS = "pass";
```

This method is used for creating Database.

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +COL_ID + " integer autoincrement," + COL_NAME + " text," + COL_PASS+ " text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

// INSERTING ROW IN DATABASE

public void insertData(int id, String name, String pass){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_ID, id);
    values.put(COL_NAME, name);
    values.put(COL_PASS, pass);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
}
```

This is MainActivity.java class. I think I'm getting problem in defining the DatabaseHelper class because before when i defined this outside the onCreate method it make app crash then i saw some code which tell me to define it inside the onCreate method but still it didnt work for me.

```
package com.example.ankurnamikaze.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
EditText name, password;
String user_name, user_pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
    user_name = String.valueOf(name.getText());
    user_pass = String.valueOf(password.getText());
    databaseHelper.insertData(id, user_name, user_pass);
}
}
```

This is activiy_main.xml, in this I create the attributes. And I don't think this is the source of problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ankurnamikaze.myapp.MainActivity">


<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="USERNAME"
android:id="@+id/user_name"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="PASSWORD"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="sumbit"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: how exactly is it not running? Does it not compile, or crash, or what?

Comment: Should i add the compile line given by android studio?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors/issues.

### Issue 1

You have coded `" integer autoincrement,"` this will result in a syntax error as the AUTOINCREMENT keyword can only be used with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (saying that it's not recommended to use it as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is more efficient and has very much the same result, that is automatically generating a unique id (actually it only makes the id an alias of the rowid in either situation)).[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

e.g.

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed

The error would result in something along the lines of the following :-

```
09-19 07:32:10.040 7200-7200/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "autoincrement": syntax error
09-19 07:32:10.040 7200-7200/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-19 07:32:10.040 7200-7200/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62e9288)
09-19 07:32:10.044 7200-7200/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{so52399661.so52399661/so52399661.so52399661.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table notes (id integer autoincrement,name text,pass text)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table notes (id integer autoincrement,name text,pass text)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
        at so52399661.so52399661.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:23)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at so52399661.so52399661.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:38)
        at so52399661.so52399661.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Instead I'd suggest just coding :-

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_PASS+ " TEXT)");
```

### Issue 2

You have no id **user_pass** defined in the layout.

### Issue 3

**id** cannot be resolved (see below this isn't needed).

### Solution

The following is the fixed code (see comments) with some additional code to list the tables in the Database :-

**activity_main.xml** (id user_pass added to PASSWORD EditText) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:id="@+id/user_name"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="sumbit"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DatabaseHelper.java** (see comments) :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes_db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    public static final String COL_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_PASS = "pass";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +COL_ID + " integer autoincrement," + COL_NAME + " text," + COL_PASS+ " text)"); //<<<<<<<<<< ERROR
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_PASS+ " TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

// INSERTING ROW IN DATABASE

    //<<<<<<<<<< as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then id will be automatically generated
    public void insertData(String name, String pass){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(COL_ID, id); not needed will autogenerate
        values.put(COL_NAME, name);
        values.put(COL_PASS, pass);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** (see comments) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    EditText name, password;
    String user_name, user_pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
        user_name = String.valueOf(name.getText());
        user_pass = String.valueOf(password.getText());
        //databaseHelper.insertData(id, user_name, user_pass); //<<<<<<<<<< got rid of id
        databaseHelper.insertData(user_name, user_pass);

        //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to List the tables
        Cursor csr = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("TABLES","Found table " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

### Result in the Log :-

```
09-19 07:10:20.628 6977-6977/so52399661.so52399661 D/TABLES: Found table android_metadata
    Found table notes
```

i.e. you **notes** table exists, android_metedata is a table created by the SQLiteOpenhelper class that you DatabaseHelper is a subclass of. It contains the locale.

Comment: Thank you so much, well i also have a question that Does sqlite support NOT null because I don't think it works like in SQL and what else you can suggest me if user left any column without entering data. I hope you understand what i want to say..

Comment: @FootstaR `db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COL_PASS+ " TEXT NOT NULL)");` will result in a conflict if name or pass are null. However, I'd suggest checking the length of the strings returned from user_pass.getText().toString() and user_name.getText().toString() if the length of either is < 1 then Toast message. e.g. if((user_name.getText().toString()).length < 1 || (user_pass.getText().toString).length < 1) { ...do toast...} else { ....do the insert...}

Comment: @FootstaR NOTE if you change the structure (such as adding NOT NULL) then you need do something like Delete the App's Data or uninstall the App (this is because the onCreate method of the database helper only runs when the database is created.)

Comment: @FootstaR lastly, if the answer answered your question then you should click the tick mark to indicate that the question has been answered.